# How do I print 3 lists side by side in python?

Tags: list, tuples

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c,']
b = [1, 2, 3]
c = [1, 2, 3]


#this is my effort on printing 3 lists side by side; however, I noticed it is completely wrong
res = "\n".join("{} {}".format(x, y, z) for x, y, z in zip(a, b, c))
        print(res)
```

#how i want my results to look like
a   1   1
b   2   2
c   3   3

I was expecting to print 3 lists side by side

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2, 3]
c = [1, 2, 3]

i = 0
while i < len(a) and i < len(b) and i < len(c):
    print(a[i], end=' ')
    print(b[i], end=' ')
    print(c[i], end=' ')
    i += 1
```